# Can't test user name validation with TestUnit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, testing

I have the following validation in my User model:

```
  validates :name, :format => {
    :with    => /^[a-zA-Z]+$/,
    :message => 'Only letters allowed.'
  }
```

And here is my test:

```
  test 'name must consist of letters only' do
    user = User.new(:name => 'test123')
    assert user.errors[:name].any?
  end
```

Test always fails. What do I do wrong? xD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your assert is the opposite of what it should be. Invert the condition of your assert.

Try this

```
test 'name must consist of letters only' do
  user = User.new(:name => 'test123')
  assert !user.valid?
end
```

Also, try using `validates_format_of` instead of `validate`

```
validates_format_of :name, :with    => /^[a-zA-Z]+$/, :message => 'Only letters allowed.'
```

Comment: Here is my logic: I validate that name is letters only. In test I add name which is 'test123', so there must be errors for :name. So errors.any? must return true. Assert is true. Where do I do wrong?

Comment: @Konnigun Sorry - I goofed up, and am confused. Give me a moment.

Comment: @Konnigun - try using `valid?` method instead as I have edited.

Comment: Thank you. While `user.valid?` definetly works, I need to test exactly this one piece and not the whole user which has many other validations too. I tried `validates_format_of` also as you suggested, no effect sadly xD

Comment: [Errors Api Doc](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Errors.html) does not mention `any?`. Instead could you then try `assert !user.errors[:name].empty?` ?

Comment: `assert user.errors[:name].empty?` returns true, meaning that there are no validation errors. Both test and rails console tell me user is invalid when I type name like "test1234", and they both say user is valid when I type name like "test", but I can't figure out where exactly this only format piece I need is located.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25913/discussion-between-srikanth-venugopalan-and-konnigun)

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what my problem was:
I should've done `user.valid?`, `user.invalid?` or `user.save` before trying to access `user.errors`. Those commands above produce errors actually, and after that I could access them.
Final result:

```
  validates_format_of :name, :with => /^[a-zA-Z]+$/, :message => 'Only letters allowed'

  test 'name must consist of letters only' do
    user = User.new(:name => 'test123')
    user.save
    assert user.errors[:name].any?
  end
```

Comment: Oh Yes! I didn't realize we weren't calling `save`. Damn.

Comment: Haha ye, funny stuff and so lame ^^